# how to exclude elements with xpath

Tags: xpath

This is my xpath query:

```
//div[contains(@class,"group") and contains(@class,"group-even")]//div[descendant-or-self::text()]
```

It will take content from:

```
<div class="service-group">
<div class="group group-even">...</div>
<div class="group">...</div>
</div>
```

Which is fine BUT it also takes content from:

```
<div class="service-group">
...
<div id="lastCollectionHours" class="group lastCollectionHours">...</div>
...
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="service-group">
...
<div id="retailHours" class="group group-even retailHours">
    ...
</div>
```

I want to exclude these two divs, how can I do?

Comment: BTW, can you give an example of `contains(@class, "group-even") and not(contains(@class, "group"))`?

Comment: That will exclude content from <div class="group"> which I need.

Comment: In the question, you select `@class` that contains both `group` and `group-even`. My point was just that the first condition is useless - if a string contains `group-even`, it also contains `group`.

Comment: I just updated my question these two divs you were talking about are not nested. Just two separate div's.

Answer (score 0):

The basis for exclusion is unclear, but to literally exclude the two nodes you specified:

```
div[
    contains(@class, "group") and
    not(
        @id = "retailHours" or
        @id = "lastCollectionHours"
    )
]//...
```

http://www.xmlplayground.com/YI3Pe4